# Is there any preference on the order of select and filter in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We have two approaches to selecting and filtering data from spark data frame `df`. First:

```
df = df.filter("filter definition").select('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
```

and second:

```
df = df.select('col1', 'col2', 'col3').filter("filter definition")
```

Suppose we want call the action  of `count` after that.
Which one is more performant if we can change the place of `filter` and `select` in spark (I mean in definition of the filter we use from the selected columns and not more)? Why? Is there any difference to the `filter` and `select` swapping for different actions or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spark ( in and above 1.6 version) uses [catalyst optimiser](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) for queries, so less performant query will be transformed to the efficient one.

[image]

Just to confirm you can call explain(true) on dataframe to check its optimised plan which are the same for both the queries.

**Query1 plan:**
[image]

**Query2 plan:**
[image]

PS: New changes are introduction of [cost based optimiser.](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/08/31/cost-based-optimizer-in-apache-spark-2-2.html)

Answer (score -2):

Yes you can notice a difference if you are dealing with a huge amount of data where it has huge number of columns

```
df = df.filter("filter definition").select('col1', 'col2', 'col3')
```

This would filer on the condition first and then select the required columns

```
df = df.select('col1', 'col2', 'col3').filter("filter definition")
```

This is the other way around where it selects the columns first and applies the filter next

***DIFFERENCE***

It all depends if you are filtering based on the columns that you select its always better to use the select followed by the filer as it selects the columns before the filter where the amount of time for filer will reduce as there is an exponential increase in data but if you are applying the filter on some other columns then i would always recommend you to select the columns which are applying filter along with the columns you want and then apply the filer as its much faster compared to applying the filer on the entire DF

so always go with below to save time on the transformation.

**`df = df.select('col1', 'col2', 'col3').filter("filter definition")`**

Comment: I have added another answer. Please check.

Comment: This might be true in some cases, but in general it won't be. Recent versions of Spark contain a query optimizer. Most RDBMSes will also optimize queries like this.